# sed: unescaped newline inside substitute pattern?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, escaping

This code:

```
echo Foo | sed -e 's/Foo/Bar'
```

results in `unescaped newline inside substitute pattern` (instead of the expected `Bar`).

I'm obviously overlooking something simple, bash/sed/escaping related, but I can't find out what's causing this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You are missing terminating `/`:

```
echo Foo | sed -e 's/Foo/Bar/'
```

Comment: Not an intuitive error message (at least until you know the solution!)  ;)  Thanks!